# How to find what is using a shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, 17.10

I normally bind my terminal to toggle visibility on the F9 key.
I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10 given it's due for full release next month I figure it's likely stable enough (and if not I can always reload!).

Anyway, Something seems to be bound to F9 by default and I cannot work out what it is (nothing listed under global shortcuts).

Pressing the key does nothing. Binding the terminal toggle to F12 as an example works fine.

So, How can I tell what is intercepting the F9 key?